# Module `scheduler` does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, yarnpkg

I am trying to run existing expo project.
I've cloned it and ran yarn and then expo start. and got this error:

Unable to resolve module `scheduler` from `/path-to-project/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-prod.js`: Module `scheduler` does not exist in the Haste module map

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968

Tried to solve it by:

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
5. deleted and cloned project again multiple times
6. deleted node_modules and reinstalled
7. reinstalled watchman, npm and updated brew.
8. Installed latest version of schedule package (0.5.0) instead of (0.4.0)

Clues:
When trying to run iOS simulator, the budling gets stuck at %99

```
Building JavaScript bundle [================================= ] 99%
```

after that:

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved by adding those versions into my project.

```
"expo": "^35.0.0",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-dom": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-web": "^0.11.7"
```

However, I got other issues by updating expo version.